# In-process cache VS. Out-of-process cache

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-caching

I've been working on a small webpage where I display a grid-view with database table records in. I also have an option for the user to add a record to the DB, or update an existing record.

Currently I use simple sql queries for all these and my db is small so it's fine for now. Though I would like to prepare myself for larger db's so I would like to implement caching to make the display, insert and update commands faster. I've read about two kinds of caches: in-process cache, and out-of-process cache.

Can someone please explain or refer me to an explanation about the difference between the two, and how to implement them with Azure in C#? Suppose I want the reads to be with in-proc cache and the writes with out-of-proc cache, can I do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend that you decide on the caching mechanism based on the application type and requirements.

Please go through the following links

1. [Azure Basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790849%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)
2. [Azure Client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790941%28v=azure.10%29.aspx)
3. [Caching Strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708748.aspx)
4. [High Availability](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790974.aspx)
5. [Caching Capacity Planning Guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg186017.aspx)

Also please post additional details so that the community can look into and suggest the right approach. Also note the Appfabric also supports local caching. You can explore on that area also.

Comment: Is the AppFabric Caching discussed in the links considered an in-proc cache of out-of-proc cache?

Comment: App fabric is out of process. It is a distributed caching mechanism where your cache can reside in a cluster of servers.

Comment: OK that will help me a lot thanks! Do you have any documentation also for in-process cache in azure?

Comment: Here is a link that explains the local cache: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790983(v=azure.10).aspx and this link provides with samples: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790857(v=azure.10).aspx. Also I have updated the post with few more links on App fabric caching like the availability concerns and the capacity planning guides.

Comment: LAST QUESTION! All those code that is written there, where should it be? Should I create a new role or just add it to the Webrole (sorry I'm pretty new at c#)?

Comment: These codes will be part of your application, typically the `Service` layer in your app, along with the required configuration files.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29816/discussion-between-user1067083-and-saravanan)